Microsoft Entra ID - Consent page does not appear for custom scope
I created a custom scope called 'contato' and assigned permissions to it, but when I request access to this scope, Microsoft Entra does not display the consent page. Instead, it first shows the login page and then immediately redirects the user to the redirect URI, without showing any consent prompt for my scope.
Note: There was no consent approval before requesting access to the scope, meaning the consent page should have been displayed.
API Permission Menu
Thats my C# code:
c# code, Authorization Code Flow

It does not show the consent prompt because your app is asking for a scope to itself.
Consent allows applications to make requests to other applications' APIs on behalf of a user with the granted permissions.
An app does not need this permission for itself and is allowed to use any scope to itself it wants.

Thanks Juunas. You are right. Super simple. Just a concept that I misunderstood
